# how mybatis process Boolean field using mysql type tinyint?

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I use mysql type tinyint(1) for rabbitmqFlag field.BUT,not as excepted,actually,the value -1 or >0 will map to true.other will map to false.
Usually,we think 0 is false,other is true.Why?

```
@Data
public class User implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    private Boolean rabbitmqFlag;

}

@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM user1 WHERE rabbitmq_flag = 0")
    List<User> findUnSend();

}
```

Comment: what are you trying to ask...???

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.  Go through this https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Answer (score 0):

MyBatis does not *process* the numeric value.
It just returns the result of `ResultSet#getBoolean`.

According to the driver's source code [comment](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/16a712ddb3f826a1933ab42b0039f7fb9eebc6ec/src/main/core-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/result/BooleanValueFactory.java#L55), it's for compatibility with the ODBC driver, etc..

```java
public Boolean createFromLong(long l) {
  // Goes back to ODBC driver compatibility, and VB/Automation Languages/COM, where in Windows "-1" can mean true as well.
  return (l == -1 || l > 0);
}
```

Comment: so the boolean field value actually depends on jdbc driver.should we better not use boolean field?

Comment: Or, you can write a custom boolean type handler which behaves as you want (e.g. call `ResultSet#getInt()` internally instead of `getBoolean()`). See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers) for the details.